# "Rationalizing" an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x=\sqrt[3]{p}+\sqrt[3]{q}$$

I'm trying to figure out some way to "rationalize" the previous equation, meaning to rewrite it purely in terms of whole number powers of $p$, $q$, and $x$. It seems quite simple but I've been stuck trying to do it. I'd appreciate anyone's help with this.

Comment: Not easy. If $p$ and $q$ are coprime, the polynomial has dgree $9$.

Comment: Closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010973/degree-of-an-algebraic-number-over-a-field  ;  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359054

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on Bernard's suggestion:
$$x= \sqrt[3]{p}+\sqrt[3]{q}$$
$$x(\sqrt[3]{p^2}-\sqrt[3]{pq}+\sqrt[3]{q^2})= p+q$$
$$x((\sqrt[3]{p}+\sqrt[3]{q})^2-3\sqrt[3]{pq})= p+q$$
$$x(x^2-3\sqrt[3]{pq})= p+q$$
$$x^3-3x\sqrt[3]{pq}= p+q$$
$$3x\sqrt[3]{pq}= x^3-p-q$$
$$27x^3pq= (x^3-p-q)^3$$

Comment: Aha, I now see what I missed! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Use the high school identity:
$$(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=a^3+b^3.$$

Comment: But that would leave $(\sqrt[3]{p^2}+\sqrt[3]{pq}+\sqrt[3]{q^2})x$ on the left hand side, wouldn't it?

Comment: No: you write $a+b=\dots$. So really, what you rationalise is the numerator. Btw, it's $-\sqrt[3]{pq}$ that you should write.

Answer (score 2):

Another way (maybe it's the same as Bernard's, but I don't see how):

$${x\over \sqrt[3]{q}}=1+\sqrt[3]{p\over q}\\$$
$${x^3\over q}=1+{p\over q}+3\sqrt[3]{p\over q}\left(1+\sqrt[3]{p\over q}\right)=1+{p\over q}+3x\sqrt[3]{p\over q^2}$$

And you can continue from here.